# Perform Pearson's correlation and chi-squared test for feature selection in a dataset with a mixed type of features

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-selection

I've a dataset of about 200 features and 5000 instances. These features comprise of different data types like percent (string like 4.50%), dollar amount (value between $0 - $1,000,000), discrete distribution as string (colors like red, blue), etc.

There are lots of different format in the data. I can't use a regex pattern of a feature in another feature.

So how can I convert these features into float (for correlation feature selection), or into some categories (for chi-squared test and one way ANOVA test)?

Comment: What language or tool are you using for your analysis? For numeric values, the conversion should be relatively simple. You could also try binning to convert them to discrete value as required. For discrete distribution, you can probably apply one hot encoding or similar strategies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot